# algorithm and Cook theorem

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, np-complete

Let $A$ be a set of decision algorithms which are running in polynomial time and which takes natural numbers as inputs.

> $x\in A$  if and only if
>
> for $i\in N$
>
> $x(i)=0$ or $x(i)=1$
>
> and running time of $x(i)$ is smaller than $n^k$  ($n$ is digit of $i$)

Now consider a $\mathcal{NP}$  problem for the set $A$.

Problem: "For given $x\in A$, is there any $i\in N$, such that $x(i)=0$?"

For this $\mathcal{NP}$  problem, there is a decider of non-deterministic Turing machine $M$

$$
M(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1\text{ if there exists  i∈ N, such that x(i)=0 }\\
0\text{ otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

And for this NDTM, there is a verifier of polynomial Deterministic Turing Machine $V$,

$$
V(x,i) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1\text{ if x(i)=0 }\\
0\text{ otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

> Question : By the Cook-Levin theorem, I think something can be transformed into a Boolean formula. What is transformed into a Boolean formula?

$M$? $M(x)$? $V$? $V(x)$? $x$? or the NP problem itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual version of the Cook-Levin theorem provides a transformation from the decider $M$, but the truth value of the variables is (partially) set by the input $x$. That is, there are variables of the form $S_{i,\rho}$ which are true if the $i$<sup>th</sup> symbol on the input tape is $\rho$ (so you have about $n\times|\Sigma|$ of these, where $n$ is the length of encoding of the input and $\Sigma$ is the input alphabet).

It would not be too hard to imagine that there would be an alternate proof that usese $V$ instead of $M$. Indeed, Levin's proof mapped from *search* problems, rather than decisions problems anyway. The key part in any such proof though is that we need to be able to map *any* problem in $\mathcal{NP}$ to SAT. Thus we need to use some universal property of all problems in $\mathcal{NP}$, such as that they all have a NDTM that decides them, or a DTM that verifies them.

Comment: Thanks @Luke. Let A be a set of all NP problem. Let B be a set of all decider of NP problem. Let C be a set of all verifier of NP problem. Let D be a set of all Boolean formula. You mean that there are transformations from A to D, from B to D, from C to D respectively?

Comment: @HoCheolSHIN, yes, though the Cook-Levin theorem is typically B -> D.